# new after variable name in javascript .. why?

Tags: javascript

in some variable why we but NEW after variable name in javascript
like

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

or

```
var xhr = new data;
```

why is that ?

Comment: [**"new" operator on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 1):

It means you are instantiating an object from a class. Primitive types like ints don't need to be instantiated because they are not objects.